# Items not removed from List

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code. In my test planList collection has 150 items. After deleting count is 75 which means that 75 items was removed from the list. Why after that countItems list is 150.
It seems that items not removed from the list. Why? How I can remove items from the list.

```
...
planList = (IList<UserPlanned>)_jsSerializer.Deserialize(plannedValues,typeof(IList<UserPlanned>));
int count = planList.ToList().RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);
int countItems = planList.Count;
...
```

Comment: You are getting the `Count` of a *different* list... removing the `ToList()` call would ensure you are referring to the same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be something like

```
lanList = (List<UserPlanned>)_jsSerializer.Deserialize(plannedValues,typeof(List<UserPlanned>));

int count = planList.RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);

int countItems = planList.Count;
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call ToList() it is copied your list, then you remove items from copy. Use:

```
int count = planList.RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are removing elements from the list that is created by ToList method, not from planList itself.

Answer (score 1):

`ToList()` is creating a different list that you are removing items from. This is essentially what you're doing:

```
var list1 = (List<UserPlanned>)_jsSerializer.Deserialize(plannedValues,typeof(List<UserPlanned>));
var list2 = list1.ToList(); // ToList() creates a *new* list.

list2.RemoveAll(eup => eup.Id <= -1);

int count = list2.Count;
int count2 = list1.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var templst = planList.ToList();
int count = templst.RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);
int countItems = templst.Count;
```

that should work. As mentioned above, the tolist command creates a new list, from which the values are deleted.
I do not know the type Of your planList, but if it is already a List, you could simply omit the .tolist

```
int count = planList.RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);
```

excuse the shaky c#, I am writing vb.net normally

Answer (score 0):

```
planList = (List<UserPlanned>)_jsSerializer.Deserialize(plannedValues,typeof(List<UserPlanned>));
int count = planList.RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);
int countItems = planList.Count;
```

Remove the `ToList()`. This is creating a new list in memory so you never actually update your underlying list. You also don't need it.

Comment: Sorry, return type is IList. I changed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

planList has not been changed.

```
planList.ToList()  //This creates a new list.
.RemoveAll()       //This is called on the new list.  It is not called on planList.
```

Answer (score 0):

The planList.ToList() creates a new list that RemoveAll operates on. It does not modify the IEnumerable planList.

Try something like this:

```
planList = (List<UserPlanned>)_jsSerializer
     .Deserialize(plannedValues,typeof(List<UserPlanned>))
    .ToList();
int count = planList.RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);
int countItems = planList.Count;
```

If you are using the JavaScriptSerializer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx_
Then try this:

```
planList = _jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<UserPlanned>>(plannedValues);

int count = planList.RemoveAll(eup => eup.ID <= -1);
int countItems = planList.Count;
```